# Rails 3: How can i use custom table column as id instead of the regular table id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a table and because of specific reasons i have to use a custom table column as an id:

table representations has columns id and i want to use column edavis_id instead of the id.

```
#app/models/representation.rb:  

class Representation < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :people_attributes, :name, :country_id, :rep_type_id, :address, :address_postal, :phone, :email, :fax, :homepage, :consular_district, :botschaftsfunk, :ivs, :ivpn, :idirect

  belongs_to :country
  belongs_to :rep_type

  has_many :people
  has_many :representation_telephones, foreign_key: :representation_id

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :people

  validates_uniqueness_of :remedy_site_id, allow_nil: true

  has_many :device_representation_relations
  has_many :devices, :through => :device_representation_relations

  delegate :name_de, to: :rep_type, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
  delegate :iso_code, to: :country, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
  # omitted...
end
```

How can i tell rails to use edavis_id as id (instead of the regular table id)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
class Representation < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = :edavis_id
  #        
end
```

http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-override-default-primary-key-id-in-rails/

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what i was asking for!

Answer (score 0):

Just add this:

```
 class Representation < ActiveRecord::Base
   self.primary_id = :edavis_id
   #...
 end
```